# Login github package registry in private repository from github action service

Tags: docker, github-actions, github-package-registry

we are trying to use a private docker image hosted on the Github Package of our organization. Something like this:

```yaml
on: push

jobs:
  runner-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      postgres:
        # Github Registry image here
        image: ghcr.io/orgname/reponame:tag
```

But we are getting an unauthorized error, which is normal, becuase the registry is private. Is there some way to login? I have not found any way or docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add [credentials](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idservicesservice_idcredentials) to each service where you use an image from a private repository. From the docs:

> If the image's container registry requires authentication to pull the image, you can use `credentials` to set a `map` of the `username` and `password`. The credentials are the same values that you would provide to the [docker login](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/) command.

And here is an example:

```yaml
on: push

jobs:
  runner-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      postgres:
        image: ghcr.io/orgname/reponame:tag
        # add this to each service with an image from a private repo
        credentials:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USER }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
```

This example implies that you have two [secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets): `DOCKER_USER` and `DOCKER_PASSWORD`.